# android MediaPlayer without prepare() method

Tags: android

The following code to play the test_audio.mp3 using `MediaPlayer` `Object` works without calling the `prepare()` method. What problems may arise if the `prepare()` method is not called.

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test_audio);
mp.start();
```

Comment: problem is what the problams may arise if you call it... please read the doc

Answer (score 4):

The static `create()` method on `MediaPlayer` does a `prepare()` for you, as is noted in [the documentation for that method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20int%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can have problems with playing big local files.